# How to block particular URL only in Firefox (Not the entire domain)?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, url, blocking

I'm using a site `www.abc.com` . I need to block only `www.abc.com/advertisement`  and I have to load all other urls in that website? How can I achieve this in firefox? I really need to use that website but the Ads are disgusting. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try using Adblock extension?

Comment: Add block already installed.It's not blocking that Ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the already suggested Adblock (Edge eventually) you can also use [leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/leechblock/) which comes very handy when you want to put a site (or pattern) on the fly in the blockist.